# Can you have a timestamp in the Microsoft Advanced Hunting Security API POST request

Tags: http-post, mde

For the Advanced Hunting API (https://api.security.microsoft.com/api/advancedhunting/run), is there a way to add the timestamp in the POST request?

I currently have a hunt e.g.

```
DeviceProcessEvents
| where Timestamp >= ago(25h)
| where ProcessCommandLine has_any (".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif")
| count
```

I want to be able to send the POST request with the timestamp in the request rather than in the query. This is so that I can change the time scale in the POST request for all of my hunts rather than have to change the timestamp in each individual hunt. Thank you!